# change android's media DATE_TAKEN format

Tags: android

I am obtaining the date image was captured using

```
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
    String dateAdded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

The result i get is dateFormat = 1430334035295

How do I convert dateAdded into a proper MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss format??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);

String dateTime = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(dateAdded)));
```